# Sending multiple json requests(load test) using SoapUI

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I am pretty new to SoapUI tool. I am using SoapUI version 5.3.0 My Application have a couple of RESTful APIs. I have to send a request to the WebService in the form of a json request as below:

```
{
"app_key":"i8gAVDwcAq40n2kAv6Ox+w==",
"targetDB":"100",
"createNew": "true"
}
```

As of now I am able to send single request in each step and get back a satisfactory response as below:

```
<StartDataExtractResult xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AriaTechCore" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<StatusCode>1</StatusCode>
<StatusText>success</StatusText>
<RequestNumber>100</RequestNumber>
</StartDataExtractResult>
```

My question is how can I send multiple requests (50, 100, 500) requests in a loop to the Web Server changing the property "targetDB" (e.g. 100, 101, 102...) in 1 second interval?

Using Soap UI 5.3.0.

Any help/pointers will be very helpful.

This is how my Project looks like:
[My Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxV0G.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

[Create a test case](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html) with the following steps:

- Groovy Script Test Step - which will generate a number with required logic to generate the number for `targetDB`
- Request Test Step - which you have currently. But here the generated number needs to be used.

**Groovy Script**

```
def targetdb = ((context.expand('${#TestCase#TARGET_DB}') ?: 0) as Integer) + 1
log.info "Target db for current request : ${targetdb}"
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('TARGET_DB', targetdb.toString())
```

Request : change request to be able to use generated `target db` using property expansion.

```
{
   "app_key":"i8gAVDwcAq40n2kAv6Ox+w==",
   "targetDB":"${#TestCase#TARGET_DB}",
   "createNew": "true"
}
```

Just right click on the test case, choose `New Load Test`.

There are different strategies for load testing. Of course, it allows you to set the number of times a test needs to be executed.

You can find more details [here](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/creating-and-running-loadtests.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried to implement the groovy script suggested by you with all sorts of possible values e.g. << def targetdb = (context.expand('${#startDataExtract#TARGET_DB}')  as  Integer ?: 0 ) + 1
log.info "Target db for current request : ${targetdb}"
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('TARGET_DB', targetdb.toString())>> but each time I am facing a NumberFormat Exception as follows `java.lang.NumberFormatException: for input string: "" error at line:1`

Comment: @Dev, sorry about, fixed the issue and updated the answer. Please try it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. Now the Groovy Script is generating database names as expected. I have even created the Load Test. But now when I try to execute the Testcase (i.e. startDataExtract) which is having 2 TestSteps as (1.Groovy Script & 2. startDATAextract webservice call), I am facing an error. I have observed the Request Message which is much similar to my previous Request Messages. The error says `Error occurred while validating database, Please check appropriate database connection or permissions` I have added Project snapshot in Description. Any suggestions please.

Comment: I would appreciate if you accept the answer for the posted question. If you have new question, feel free to open new question with reproducible steps.

Comment: upon digging a bit further I found a log message in my application as `Incorrect database name ''`

Comment: [How to accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sir, thanks again. I will surely accept the it as a solution to my question.The problem is json property "targetDB" in TestStep "startDATAextract" is still not accepting the database name which is being generated through the Groovy Script. Can you please help me out further?

Comment: It is becuase you did not follow the the instruction as it is. You have to use `${#TestCase#TARGET_DB}`. You have modified the value in place of `TestCase` which is the reason and is a reserved key. Just use as it is given in the answer. You should not do what is not suggested, instead try as given in first before modifying to your application.

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much. Now I am able to send multiple requests as per my specification.

Comment: Your screen shot helped. Otherwise could not figured out the strange reason. Any ways, glad to know that it helped.